# Make enum with return Class inheriting Codable to parse JSON to your model class

Tags: ios, json, swift, urlsession

I need to make an enum to return class type to using in another function to parse my JSON to model.

Below follows an example of what I wrote.

```
enum APIType {
  case status

  var responseType: AnyClass {
    switch self {
    case .status:
      return MyModel.self
    }
  }
}
```

But, one error occurred which I assume is happening due to Codable inheritance.

**Cannot convert return expression of type 'MyClass.Type' to return type 'AnyClass' (aka 'AnyObject.Type')**

Has anyone gone through this challenge? How do I resolve this?

Comment: `AnyClass` is for classes, my guess is that you are using struct. Try `Any` instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is actually quite clear, you are trying to return the class type of an object, but the compiler expects a concrete implementation of any class.

Just replace the return value of `responseType` to be AnyObject.Type

```
class MyModel {

}
enum APIType {
  case status

    var responseType: AnyObject.Type {
    switch self {
    case .status:
      return MyModel.self
    }
  }
}
print(APIType.status.responseType) // MyModel
```